# SwiftUI - Errors creating layout with var references

Tags: swift, layout, swiftui, native

I am trying to create a master/detail app with Xcode.

I created my project out of a template and I am trying to create a special layout in the detail view that I call EditingView.

I read the SwiftUI tutorial and it seems to be simple but in practice I found several obstacles.

I decided to put a separate view into this portion of code:

```
struct DetailView: View {
var selectedDate: Date?

var body: some View {
    
    Group{
    EditingView
      
    }.navigationBarTitle(Text("Detail"))
}
}
```

The EditingView is something like

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI

final class EditingView: View
{
  var body:  some View {
var mainVertical: VStack
                            {
…
…
…

                        }
}
}
```

In fact the above code snippet are one of several variants I tried, each leading to strange errors.

My goal is to create a layout and at the same time having the references to controls, like

```
var myButton:Button()
```

With these references a complex problem of types and return values arises.

But also without them I get errors like it needs parameter type on every control like
VStack<>
or Button<>

Errors have the fix option that writes something that is unrecognized too by the compiler, leading to more errors and complexity.

It is a mess, nothing works, EditingView has to be final but if I put the final keyword it is the same, then it says it does not conform to View protocol. Then is starts complaining about initializers, closures and so on.

I strongly want to stick on native but Am I missing something on Xcode?
You experienced programmers what do you think? Is there solution to have at least a minimum working example?
I have latest Xcode version.

Answer (score 1):

There is no other code but any SwiftUI View **must** be a struct, so

```
struct EditingView: View         // << here !!
{
  var body:  some View {
  ...
```

Comment: That is not true. A `final class` can also conform to `View`. See `final class MyView: View { var body: some View { EmptyView() } }`